# HTTPServlet error in runttime

Tags: gwt, servlets, equinox

I am deploying a GWT application on Equinox. It runs, but when I launch an event to call server, I have an error like this:

```
<title>Error 500 non-HTTP request or response</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /zbapp/zbapp/app. Reason:
<pre>    non-HTTP request or response</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: non-HTTP request or response

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:715)

at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(ServletManager.java:180)

at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)

at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:126)

at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:318)

at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)

at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)

at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)

at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)

at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)

at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)

at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)

at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:939)

at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)

at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)

at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)

at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)

at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

</pre>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>
```

My web.xml is:

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>main.java.com.gwt.app.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/zbapp/app</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I do not know what is the eral cause of that error. I have overriden service method from HttpServlet in the implementation of GWT Service.

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

It fails because of this reason

```
try {
        request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ServletException("non-HTTP request or response");
    }
```

The ***Request/Response*** is not of ***HttpServletRequest/HttpServletResponse*** type.

Somewhere in the code you are trying to wrap ***request/response using a class  which extends ServletRequest/ServletResponse***. If the application wants to ***wrap a request/response, the wrapper class should ideally extend HttpServletRequestWrapper/HttpServletResponseWrapper***.

Comment: It's easy to copypaste the source code. But this does technically not answer the question. **Why** does this occur? What can OP do to fix it?

Comment: @BaluC Application might be having some request wrapper which extends ServletRequest but not HttpServletRequest. Am i right?

Comment: I check the application and the request/responser are from HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse. However my problem solves when I have changed the target of Equinox. I don't have explanation